# can we use same container for different topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have two different topics for Kafka. The datatype and structure of data (Json) is same in both topics.
Can I use same listener container for both the topics?
I tried using and I was able to get the output consumed from both topics.

Below are my configurations.

```java
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer factoryConfigure,
    ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factoryConfigure.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    return factory;
}
```

This is my listener.

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "#{'${spring.kafka.listener.id}'}", topics = "#{'${spring.kafka.consumer.topic}'}", groupId = "#{'${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}'}")
public void getTopics( List<Request> model) {

    System.out.println("I am from topic1");
    System.out.println(model);

}

@KafkaListener(id = "#{'${spring.kafka.listener.id2}'}", topics = "#{'${spring.kafka.consumer.topic2}'}", groupId = "#{'${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id2}'}")
public void getTopics( List<Request> model) {

System.out.println("I am from topic2");
System.out.println(model);

}
```

I am not explicitly using any annotation to give name of container.
Can that lead me to any issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are asking; the container factory will create a different container for each listener.

The `topics` property is an array so you can use

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "#{'${spring.kafka.listener.id}'}", 
    topics = { "${spring.kafka.consumer.topic}",
               "${spring.kafka.consumer.topic2}" },
    groupId = "#{'${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}'}")
public void getTopics( List<Request> model) {

    System.out.println("I am from both topics");
    System.out.println(model);

}
```

If you need to know which topic each record came from, you can use

```java
public void getTopics( List<Request> model,
     @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) List<String> topics) {
```

The topic at index n is for the record at model index n.

Comment: Thanks Gary for replying. I have separate listeners cause i want to have different processing logic for them. Will annotation on listener  containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory" will be autobound here? Also is it possible to prioritise any topic ?

Comment: Yes; see the javadocs for the annotation - that is the default factory bean name. I am not sure what you mean by "prioritize".

Comment: I wanted to pause consuming  from one topic(low priority) for sometime if data is in another topic(high). I wanted  records in higher priority topics to be processed first.

Comment: You can use the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean to get a reference to the containers (using their `id`). You can then pause/resume (or stop/start) the container(s) that way. You can also set the `autoStartup` property to `false` to stop them starting automatically. Also see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#sequencing

Comment: Thanks this is much useful